# Number of times a name appears in a list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list

I have created a list, where people can nominate other employees to be recognized. At the moment the list just shows all the nominations.

I would like it to be displayed like:

```
joe bloggs 5
Paul bloggs 4
steve 2
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You could create a grouped view by person and that would generate a total beside their name.

Comment: ah of course, i should of thought of that! Thank you. Next bit is even trickier, the person column is linked to our contact list so that helps, but i would like sharepoint to send email notifications to the person nominated. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You may create a view and in the view settings, select group by based on the 'Person' column.

Comment: Thank you, is it then possible to have the employee's with the most votes on top of the list?